# Android spinner - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method help

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I have followed a tutorial to populate data from an sqlite database in to a spinner (dropdown) in Android. However, I am getting the error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method fetchAllCategories() from the type DatabaseAdapter
```

My code is as follows:

In EditTask:

```
private void fillData() {
        Cursor categoriesCursor;
        Spinner categoriesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinDept);
        categoriesCursor = DatabaseAdapter.fetchAllCategories();

        startManagingCursor(categoriesCursor);

        String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseAdapter.CAT_NAME };

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvDBViewRow }; //this part hasnt been implemented in to the layout yet

        SimpleCursorAdapter categoriesAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.db_view_row, categoriesCursor, from, to);

        categoriesSpinner.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter);
    }
```

And in my DatabaseAdapter class I have the following:

```
public Cursor fetchAllCategories() {
    if (mDb == null) {
        this.open();
    }
    String tableName = "CAT_TABLE";
    return mDb.query(tableName, new String[] { CAT_ID, CAT_NAME }, null,
            null, null, null, null);
}
```

The offending line of code is:

```
categoriesCursor = DatabaseAdapter.fetchAllCategories();
```

I'm pretty new to Java/Android so it may be something simple/obvious but any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to first instantiate a DatabaseAdapter object.
eg:

```
DatabaseAdapter myDbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter();
categoriesCursor = myDbAdapter.fetchAllCategories();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the second section of code brings up further errors such as: "Cannot use this in a static context" and "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field mDb". Using the first section also creates errors such as: The method fetchAllCategories() is undefined for the type DatabaseAdapter

Comment: You have to replace DatabaseAdapter with the class name you used in your own implementation.

Comment: The classname is DatabaseAdapter, it said the constructor needs another argument so I just used DatabaseAdapter myDbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(null); which seems to have solved this but I still get an error with categoriesCursor which is: categoriesCursor cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

to be able to make your code work, you need to declare the method fetchAllCategoires() as static as follows:

```
public static Cursor fetchAllCategories()
```

Because you have not instantiated a DatabaseAdapter object, you cannot just call one of it's methods by a class name reference unless the keyword static appears in the method declaration.

Comment: I tried this before but unfortunately it brings up further errors such as: "Cannot use this in a static context" and "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field mDb"

Comment: ahh, regarding the mDb error, that is probably because mDb is a global variable that is not declared as static. You should most probably try to instantiate your class and call the fetchAllCategories() method on the instance.